# Pandas: Passing a list through describe()

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to describe() a column from df but for every unique value in another column.I have the df:

> ```
> id revenue country 
> 1  128     at
> 2  130     de
> 3  132     de
> 4  134     hu
> 5  136     at
> 6  138     at 
> 7  140     hu
> ```

I want to pass this :

```
df[df['Country']=='cz'].net_revenue.describe(percentiles=[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.95,0.99,0.999])
```

But for every unique value in the column Country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('country')['revenue']
         .describe(percentiles=[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.95,0.99,0.999])
      )
```

Output:

```
         count   mean       std    min    20%    40%    50%    60%    80%    90%    95%     99%    99.9%    max
country                                                                                                        
at         3.0  134.0  5.291503  128.0  131.2  134.4  136.0  136.4  137.2  137.6  137.8  137.96  137.996  138.0
de         2.0  131.0  1.414214  130.0  130.4  130.8  131.0  131.2  131.6  131.8  131.9  131.98  131.998  132.0
hu         2.0  137.0  4.242641  134.0  135.2  136.4  137.0  137.6  138.8  139.4  139.7  139.94  139.994  140.0
```